# Why are binary heaps stored in array stored as multiple pages in virtual memory?

Tags: arrays, memory, memory-management, paging, heap

In the article on Binary Heaps in Wikipedia it says

> For big heaps and using virtual memory, storing elements in an array
>   according to the above scheme is inefficient: (almost) every level is
>   in a different page

Why is that? Does it have something to do with the array being contiguous? If it is stored as a tree will it be stored across lesser pages?

Comment: Each level in the heap is in contiguous array elements.  That means that if you perform operations that use elements from different levels, you're reaching farther away in the array.  Once a level fills up a page, then accessing the level above or below it means accessing a different page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is that? Does it have something to do with the array being
>   contiguous?

Remember that the children of node `i` are in index `2i` and `2i+1`. Thus, in general, the children of a node are very, very far away from its parent in the array, thus falling out to another page. This means that for each time you go down another level, you are accessing memory locations in another page.

> If it is stored as a tree will it be stored across lesser pages?

Assuming you mean storing it directly as a tree structure using left and right pointers: it kind of depends on how smart dynamic memory allocation is, but I'd say it would be slightly better if a node and its children are allocated nearly at the same time, thus increasing the likelihood of being on the same page.